# How to create a column in sas with different combinations row wise?

Tags: sql, excel, sas, proc

I have a below dataset with 864 rows. I want to create a separate column "Group" with different 128 combinations of SCREEN, BATTERY, RAM, PROCESSOR, HD_SIZE, BUNDLED_APP, Int_Wire.

```
SCREEN BATTERY RAM  PROCESSOR HD_SIZE Bundled_App Int_Wire
------- ------- ---- --------- ------- ----------- -------- 
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       No        Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       No        Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       No        Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      HIGH      Yes       Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      HIGH      No        Yes
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       No
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       No        No
```

Solution data should look like given below :

```
SCREEN BATTERY RAM  PROCESSOR HD_SIZE Bundled_App Int_Wire  Group
------- ------- ---- --------- ------- ----------- -------- ------
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       Yes     Group 1
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       No        Yes     Group 120
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       Yes     Group 1
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       No        Yes     Group 120
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      LOW       Yes       Yes     Group 1
SMALL   LOW    LOW    LOW      HIGH      Yes       Yes     Group 2
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the Group 1 and GROUP 120?  In the future please explain the logic, don't expect us to figure it out. See this tutorial here if it answers your question: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Comment: There are about 864 rows in the present data set however I have 128 unique combinations of rows. I got it using excel. According to that, I want to assign 128 group name across the present data set.

Comment: I applied the logic given in this link but I could not find the desired Group No.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far. If you're looking for all possible combos and want to group/identify those look at CALL ALLCOMB.

Comment: Do you know all possible values for the 7 variables? It looks like most are binary, but they are not 0/1, instead some have No/Yes others LOW/HIGH. Do you want logic to generate GROUP for all possible combinations? Or just those that appear in the input data?

Answer (score 1):

this is actually a neat problem.  I assume that the values your variables can take are either low and high or yes and no. I get that from you having 7 variables and 2^7 = 128.

to get the groups that you are looking for transform your table so all low and no values are 0's and all yes and high values are 1's.  you now have a seven digit binary number.  Convert that binary number back to its decimal equivalent and you'll get a number from 0 to 127.

Comment: well, what have you tried?  SO is not a free coding service.  Happy to help you out but give it a go a see what you can come up with.  Provide your work as something that can be easily copied and pasted so others can work on what you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you code the values as 0/1 instead of text strings and you have no missing values then it easy to convert the N binary variables into a single number from 0 to (2**N -1).

```
group=input(cats(of var1-var7),binary7.) ;
```

You can add one to make the numbers go from 1 to 128 instead of from 0 to 127.

If you just want to find all of the existing combinations then you could use soemthing like PROC SUMMARY to find the combinations and then add a counter.  Or sort and use FIRST. processing to add a counter.

```
proc sort data=have ;
  by SCREEN BATTERY RAM  PROCESSOR HD_SIZE Bundled_App Int_Wire ;
run;

data groups;
  set have;
  by SCREEN BATTERY RAM  PROCESSOR HD_SIZE Bundled_App Int_Wire ;
  group + first.Int_Wire;
run;
```

But that will only handle the combinations that actually appear in your data.  If you repeat the process for a different dataset it could assign the same combination to a different group number.

If you know the possible values for each variable you could generate a dataset of all possible combinations. And then either merge the two datasets or generate a format and use that.

```
data groups;
  if 0 then set have (keep=SCREEN BATTERY RAM  PROCESSOR HD_SIZE Bundled_App Int_Wire);
  do SCREEN='SMALL','LARGE';
  do BATTERY='LOW','HIGH';
  do RAM='LOW','HIGH';
  do PROCESSOR='LOW','HIGH';
  do HD_SIZE='LOW','HIGH';
  do Bundled_App='No','Yes';
  do Int_Wire='No','Yes';
    group +1 ;
    output;
  end;
  end;
  end;
  end;
  end;
  end;
  end;
run;
```

For something in-between these extremes you could ask PROC FREQ to generate all of the possible combinations of the values in the data.

```
proc freq data=have  ;
  tables SCREEN*BATTERY*RAM*PROCESSOR*HD_SIZE*Bundled_App*Int_Wire
       / sparse noprint out=groups 
  ;
run;

data groups;
  set groups ;
  group + 1;
run;
```

But if some value, say SCREEN='LARGE', never appears in the data then it will not appear in the groups.